# printing columns in awk

Tags: awk

I am using awk in shell script and it is working as expected.

```
awk -F'^' 'BEGIN {OFS="^"} {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}'
```

When I need to change the number of columns, I simply change the print statement by adding $6,$7,$8

Is there a way to declare it in a variable and use that variable in awk?

```
columns=8
awk -F'^' 'BEGIN {OFS="^"} {print $1..$columns}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use a `for`-loop

```
 {for(i=1;i<=columns;i++)printf("%s ", $i);print '\n'}'
```

using `printf` and the `print` after the loop will give you the linefeed at the end of the line.

Answer (score 3):

Do it by defining a function.
`awk 'function col(s,e){ret="";for(i=s;i<=e;i++){ret=ret" "$i}return ret}{print col(2,6)}'`

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a shell variable using `awk -v`, and then loop through all the columns:

```
awk -v cols="$columns" '{ for (i=1; i<=cols; i++) printf (i!=cols) ? $i OFS : $i"\n" }' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This may achieve your goal:

```
column=8
awk '{print $'$column'}'
```

reference:
http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-4

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
echo 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 | awk -vnf=5 '{NF=nf}1'
1 2 3 4 5
```